# What does 'layout: absolute' do?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am making a window in ExtJS, but I'm not sure about one of the properties: layout.

I have an example below of my code.

```
var myWindow = new Ext.Window({
      height     : 300,
      width      : 300,
      layout     : 'absolute'
      //additional window code
}
```

In this case, what does the `layout: 'absolute'` property do?

Comment: So you can put textField at absolute point for example (11px, 123px)... if you want. That's about it. Don't see the point of your question, if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Extjs 3+

Absolute layout inherits the anchoring of Ext.layout.AnchorLayout and adds the ability for x/y positioning using the standard x and y component config options.

[AbsoluteLayout](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/output/Ext.layout.AbsoluteLayout.html)

Refer :

[ext-3.3.1/docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/)

Answer (score -3):

As specified in the [Ext JS Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-cfg-layout), the `layout` property controls how the component is arranged on the page.

As far as I know, and as far as I've read, there is no such layout as 'absolute' (Are you perhaps thinking of css instead of ExtJS?). What you might have meant is `layout: anchor`. An `anchor` layout allows you to anchor parts of a component relative to the container your component is in. In this case, you would specify the `anchor` layout so that child elements of the window can be anchored relative to the window.